# Laptop error while starting (check cable connection)

Tags: reboot

[image]

I'm trying to open my pc but I'm facing this issue.. I don't know what to do Pls provide the assistance

[image]

Comment: There is a hardware error inside. Can you boot to BIOS?  If so, get the manufacturer's hardware test app on bootable USB and check hardware. If not, get the machine serviced at a local shop.

Comment: No Bootable Device = it can't find your hard drive for some reason.  Maybe it went bad, bad cable, etc... looks like quite an old machine, very likely the hard disk has gone bad.

Answer (score 1):

The firmware is attempting to boot. To do that it needs to find some
device to boot from.

It will check first the disk or disks, but in the end will fall
back to searching the network for a server that contains the boot media.
This network boot is called PXE boot.

It is probable that your disk has failed, and also likely that your data
was lost. The disk can no longer be recognized as a hard disk.

Try first to open up the computer and search for a loose connection.
Press on all connectors relating to the disk.

Second, if you have another disk, try to replace it. You will need to install
the operating system from scratch. If this doesn't work, it's
possible that the motherboard has failed.
You might need help from a repair-shop.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It work